# Discord.py Music Bot doesn't play music

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying to create a music bot. It joins the voice channel but does not play music in the channel. I have downloaded all the packages including ffmpeg.

I have also checked it twice but did not find any mistakes. Could anyone please help correct my code?

```
@client.command(name='join', help='This command makes the bot join the voice channel')
    async def join(ctx):
        if not ctx.message.author.voice:
            await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel")
            return
    
        else:
            channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        await channel.connect()

@client.command(name='remove', help='This command removes an item from the list')
async def remove(ctx, number):
    global queue

    try:
        del (queue[int(number)])
        await ctx.send(f'Your queue is now `{queue}!`')

    except:
        await ctx.send('Your queue is either **empty** or the index is **out of range**')


@client.command(name='play', help='This command plays songs')
async def play(ctx):
    global queue

    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client

    async with ctx.typing():
        player = await YTDLSource.from_url(queue[0], loop=client.loop)
        voice_channel.play(player, after=lambda e: print('Player error: %s' % e) if e else None)

    await ctx.send(f'**Now playing:** {player.title} !')
    del (queue[0])


@client.command(name='pause', help='This command pauses the song')
async def pause(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client

    voice_channel.pause()


@client.command(name='resume', help='This command resumes the song!')
async def resume(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client

    voice_channel.resume()

@client.command(name='leave', help='This command stops makes the bot leave the voice channel')
async def leave(ctx):
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    await voice_client.disconnect()


@client.command(name='stop', help='This command stops the song!')
async def stop(ctx):
    server = ctx.message.guild
    voice_channel = server.voice_client

    voice_channel.stop()
```

Comment: please say a specific thing that doesn't work and send the code of the thing which is not working.

Comment: @yotamrec play command is not working , i am not able to hear any song

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
@bot.command()
async def play(ctx, url):
    voice_client = bot.voice_clients[0]
    
    ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(YTDL_OPTS)
    info = ytdl.extract_info(url, download=False)

    asrc = discord.FFmpegOpusAudio(info['formats'][0]['url'], before_options="-reconnect 1 -reconnect_streamed 1 -reconnect_delay_max 5")

    voice_client.play(asrc)
```

**Make sure you have last version of Youtube-dl, and other packages.**