# Discord.py repository example: bot can join voice channel, shows voice activity (green ring), but no sound is produced?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ffmpeg, discord, discord.py

I copied an example from the discord.py repository to test out a bot with music capabilities. Though the code enables YouTube playback, I am only concerned with local audio playback. See code here: https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/v2.3.0/examples/basic_voice.py. I tested this code as is with only the Discord token portion updated (from constants.py). See code below:

```
# This example requires the 'message_content' privileged intent to function.

#my constants.py with API keys, tokens, etc. stored
import constants

import asyncio

import discord
import youtube_dl

from discord.ext import commands

# Suppress noise about console usage from errors
youtube_dl.utils.bug_reports_message = lambda: ''


ytdl_format_options = {
    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
    'outtmpl': '%(extractor)s-%(id)s-%(title)s.%(ext)s',
    'restrictfilenames': True,
    'noplaylist': True,
    'nocheckcertificate': True,
    'ignoreerrors': False,
    'logtostderr': False,
    'quiet': True,
    'no_warnings': True,
    'default_search': 'auto',
    'source_address': '0.0.0.0',  # bind to ipv4 since ipv6 addresses cause issues sometimes
}

ffmpeg_options = {
    'options': '-vn',
}

ytdl = youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ytdl_format_options)


class YTDLSource(discord.PCMVolumeTransformer):
    def __init__(self, source, *, data, volume=0.5):
        super().__init__(source, volume)

        self.data = data

        self.title = data.get('title')
        self.url = data.get('url')

    @classmethod
    async def from_url(cls, url, *, loop=None, stream=False):
        loop = loop or asyncio.get_event_loop()
        data = await loop.run_in_executor(None, lambda: ytdl.extract_info(url, download=not stream))

        if 'entries' in data:
            # take first item from a playlist
            data = data['entries'][0]

        filename = data['url'] if stream else ytdl.prepare_filename(data)
        return cls(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(filename, **ffmpeg_options), data=data)


class Music(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.command()
    async def join(self, ctx, *, channel: discord.VoiceChannel):
        """Joins a voice channel"""

        if ctx.voice_client is not None:
            return await ctx.voice_client.move_to(channel)

        await channel.connect()

    @commands.command()
    async def play(self, ctx, *, query):
        """Plays a file from the local filesystem"""

        source = discord.PCMVolumeTransformer(discord.FFmpegPCMAudio(query))
        ctx.voice_client.play(source, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)

        await ctx.send(f'Now playing: {query}')

    @commands.command()
    async def yt(self, ctx, *, url):
        """Plays from a url (almost anything youtube_dl supports)"""

        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)

        await ctx.send(f'Now playing: {player.title}')

    @commands.command()
    async def stream(self, ctx, *, url):
        """Streams from a url (same as yt, but doesn't predownload)"""

        async with ctx.typing():
            player = await YTDLSource.from_url(url, loop=self.bot.loop, stream=True)
            ctx.voice_client.play(player, after=lambda e: print(f'Player error: {e}') if e else None)

        await ctx.send(f'Now playing: {player.title}')

    @commands.command()
    async def volume(self, ctx, volume: int):
        """Changes the player's volume"""

        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            return await ctx.send("Not connected to a voice channel.")

        ctx.voice_client.source.volume = volume / 100
        await ctx.send(f"Changed volume to {volume}%")

    @commands.command()
    async def stop(self, ctx):
        """Stops and disconnects the bot from voice"""

        await ctx.voice_client.disconnect()

    @play.before_invoke
    @yt.before_invoke
    @stream.before_invoke
    async def ensure_voice(self, ctx):
        if ctx.voice_client is None:
            if ctx.author.voice:
                await ctx.author.voice.channel.connect()
            else:
                await ctx.send("You are not connected to a voice channel.")
                raise commands.CommandError("Author not connected to a voice channel.")
        elif ctx.voice_client.is_playing():
            ctx.voice_client.stop()


intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(
    command_prefix=commands.when_mentioned_or("!"),
    description='Relatively simple music bot example',
    intents=intents,
)


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f'Logged in as {bot.user} (ID: {bot.user.id})')
    print('------')


async def main():
    async with bot:
        await bot.add_cog(Music(bot))
        #referenced my discord token in constants.py
        await bot.start(constants.discord_token)


asyncio.run(main())
```

This code should cause the Discord bot to join the voice channel and play a local audio file when the message "!play {query}" is entered into the Discord text channel, with {query} in my case being "test.mp3." When "!play test.mp3" is entered, the bot does join the voice channel and appears to generate voice activity, however no sound is heard. No errors are thrown in the output. The bot simply continues on silently.

Here's what I've checked and tried:

1. I am in the Discord voice channel. The code will alert that user is not in the voice channel if a user attempts to summon the bot without being in a voice channel.
2. FFmpeg is installed and added to PATH. I even stored a copy of the .exe in the project folder.
3. I've tried specifying the full path of both FFmpeg (adding the "executable=" arg to the play function) and the audio file (stored at C:/test.mp3 and a copy in the project folder).
4. All libraries up to date.
5. Reviewed discord.py docs (https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#voice-related) and played around with opuslib (docs say not necessary on Windows, which I'm on) and FFmpegOpusAudio, but results were the same.
6. Referenced numerous StackOverflow threads, including every one suggested when I typed the title of this post. Tried each suggestion individually and in various combinations when possible. See a few below:
   [Discord.py music_cog, bot joins channel but plays no sound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68047249/discord-py-music-cog-bot-joins-channel-but-plays-no-sound)
   [Discord.py Music Bot doesn't play music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65988272/discord-py-music-bot-doesnt-play-music)
   [Discord.py Bot Not Playing music](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64505289/discord-py-bot-not-playing-music)
7. Double checked my sound is on and volume turned up. My sound is working I can hear the Discord notification when the bot joins the voice channel.
8. Issue is the same if I try to play a YouTube file with !yt command. Bot joins channel fine but no sound is produced.

That's everything I can think of at the moment. There seem to be many posts regarding this exact topic and also variations of it. I've been unable to find a clear and consistent answer, nor one the works for me. I am willing to try anything at this point as it is obviously possible, but for whatever reason success eludes me. Thank you in advance for any assistance you are willing to offer.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/api-services-terms-of-service

against YouTube ToS just letting you know

Comment: Noted, thank you. I am only trying to utilize the local audio file playback portion of the code. I only used this code in whole as an example because it's referenced as an example by the discord.py homepage.

Comment: ok just making sure you know

Comment: I think the reason that no errors are thrown or shown is because you did not call the [discord.utils.setup_logging](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.setup_logging) function to enable `discord.py` to print out errors that could have occurred. Try calling that function in your `main` function and test your commands to see if there are actually any errors or not.

Comment: Excellent suggestion. I'll give this a shot and report back. Thanks!